# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Inspiresettings_Helper_Data' not found Tried a lot, but still the error comes

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Inspiresettings_Helper_Data' not found in
>   /home/inpxcare/public_html/brandz/app/Mage.php on line 547

Currently my `Data.php` contains

```
<?php

class Magik_Inspiresettings_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {}
{

    protected function _loadProduct(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
    {
        $product->load($product->getId());
    }

        public function getLabel(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
    {
        $html = '';
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfig("inspiresettings/inspiresettings_labels/new_label") &&
            !Mage::getStoreConfig("inspiresettings/inspiresettings_labels/sale_label") ) {
            return $html;
        }

        $this->_loadProduct($product);

        if ( Mage::getStoreConfig("inspiresettings/inspiresettings_labels/new_label") && $this->_isNew($product) ) {
                        $html .= '<div class="new-label new-'.Mage::getStoreConfig('inspiresettings/inspiresettings_labels/new_label_position').'"> '.Mage::getStoreConfig('inspiresettings/inspiresettings_labels/new_label_text').' </div>';
                }
                if ( Mage::getStoreConfig("inspiresettings/inspiresettings_labels/sale_label") && $this->_isOnSale($product) ) {
                        $html .= '<div class="sale-label sale-'.Mage::getStoreConfig('inspiresettings/inspiresettings_labels/sale_label_position').'"> '.Mage::getStoreConfig('inspiresettings/inspiresettings_labels/sale_label_text').' </div>';
                }

        return $html;
    }  

        protected function _checkDate($from, $to)
    {
        $date = new Zend_Date();
        $today = strtotime($date->__toString());

        if ($from && $today < $from) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($to && $today > $to) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$to && !$from) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }  

        protected function _isNew($product)
    {
        $from = strtotime($product->getData('news_from_date'));
        $to = strtotime($product->getData('news_to_date'));

        return $this->_checkDate($from, $to);
    }  

        protected function _isOnSale($product)
    {
        $from = strtotime($product->getData('special_from_date'));
        $to = strtotime($product->getData('special_to_date'));

        return $this->_checkDate($from, $to);
    }  
}
```

Added the class in `/app/code/local/magik/Inspiresettings/etc/config.xml` without space and case-sensitive

```
<global>
      <helpers>
        <Inspiresettings>
          <class>Magik_Inspiresettings_Helper</class>
        </Inspiresettings>
      </helpers>
    </global>
```

Code in `app/Mage.php` on line 547 is

```
/**
     * Retrieve helper object
     *
     * @param string $name the helper name
     * @return Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
     */
    public static function helper($name)
    {
        $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
        if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
            $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
            self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
        }
        return self::registry($registryKey);
    }
```

Comment: are you calling your helper from anywhere?

Comment: your class should extend Mage_Core_Helper_Data instead of Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract to add more layer

Answer (score 3):

The answer above is why you get that error- Magento can't find your helper because of the capital letter in your XML.

On a side note though, you have a syntax error on the first line of your helper - closed brace by accident I assume. You also have no public methods in your helper, which may be deliberate for extending with usable classes but I imagine it's a mistake - none of your helper methods will be usable if they stay as protected methods.

If you have magerun installed you can test your models, helper etc declarations via the command line to ensure they are configured properly:

```
n98-magerun.phar dev:class:lookup helper inspiresettings/data
```

If it resolves to your class name it is correct. If it resolves to Mage_... it's not. If you don't have magerun you should install it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to correct this line:

```
class Magik_Inspiresettings_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract //{} unnecessary 
{
...........
...........
}
```

Also change this in `config.xml`

```
<global>
  <helpers>
    <inspiresettings>
      <class>Magik_Inspiresettings_Helper</class>
    </inspiresettings>
  </helpers>
</global>
```

You should also change folder name of `magik` to `Magik` in `app/code/local`

Answer (score 1):

You have ***wrongly defined*** the helper `class group name` in `config.xml` .

You have defined it as `Inspiresettings` `(<Inspiresettings>)`but it should be in lower case letters eg. `inspiresettings` as per as Magento standards (suggestion not requirement).

```
<global>
  <helpers>
    <inspiresettings> <!-- this call module helper class group name -->
      <class>Magik_Inspiresettings_Helper</class>
    </inspiresettings>
  </helpers>
</global>
```

Also @Adarsh mentioned, the folder name should be Magik.

Also `global config file name` should be changed accordingly.

`Magik_Inspiresettings.xml` should live at `app/etc/modules`